# Assign products to a category that are not assigned to any category

Tags: category

Is there any way to assign products to a category that are not assigned to any category? I have around 1000 products that are not assigned to any category so I would like to assign them to one single category.

Comment: make a new category and add the products there in the products tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

1. Write an external script to achieve this.
2. In the script put the following code and make sure to put your category id instead what there is.

   ```
   $category_id = 8; 

   // Get all the product collection.
   $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
   foreach($collection as $product) {
       // Get categories of product.
       $cats = $product->getCategoryIds();

       // If this product doesn't have categories.
       if(count($cats) == 0) {
           // Set the category id and save.
           $product->setCategoryIds(array($category_id));
           $product->save();
       }
   }
   ```